# Communicate between VMs on connected Azure Virtual Networks

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have two virtual networks (classic) in Azure, and I need to be able to ssh between vms on these networks. I have followed the instructions here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vnet-to-vnet-connecting-virtual-networks-in-azure-across-different-regions/), and successfully connected the networks. However, when I try and ping vm1 on vnet1 and vm2 on vnet2 the request times out, so it looks like vm1 cannot see vm2. Are there any further steps I need to take to allow communication? Shouldn't they be able to see each other's private IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty loaded question, but I think there is a better walk through for you to have a look at:

[Configure a VNet-to-VNet connection in the Azure Classic Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/)

or

[Configure a VNet-to-VNet connection for virtual networks in the same subscription by using Azure Resource Manager and PowerShell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-vnet-vnet-rm-ps/)

Pick your poison... I've verified both of these work as intended if you follow the steps carefully.

Comment: Thanks, I think I must have mistyped an ip somewhere. I removed my local networks, and followed the instructions again and everything's working ok now.

Comment: Awesome! Also, I've scripted this out a bit at: https://github.com/devdash/IPContoso/blob/master/CreateNetwork.ps1. It's from April 2015, but should still work.